Browsers are using a SSL certificate that does not exist in the certificate store when running Visual Studio project
today I loaded a Visual Studio project that I was working with last year. When I tried to run it (which should load to https://localhost:44435), it gave me the "Your connection is not private" error.
I then performed
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
and deleted all subfolders from %AppData%\Microsoft\UserSecrets, and then rebooted the computer.
However, after loading the Visual Studio (2022) project and run it again, the issue still persists.
I checked the certificate from the browser and it is using one issued to localhost, but was issued on 29 Dec 2022 and expired on 29 Dec 2023. That explains why it worked last year and stopped working today. However, I am not able to locate this specific certificate in MMC, neither in the Computer account nor the user account.
I've tried Chrome, Edge, FireFox, and Opera. All having the same issue.
I've tried creating a new project and it seems to run without issues, and is properly using the SSL created from dotnet dev-certs https --trust into the certificate store.
So I cannot understand why the specific project is sticking to an expired SSL that I can't find anywhere.
From where can you force a .NET Web Application to use a specific certificate, if that's even possible?

As soon as I posted the question, I thought of searching 'SSL' in the project to see if that leads to anywhere, and it did...
My colleague who was working on the front-end of the web application had a couple of lines added into .env.development.local...
SSL_CRT_FILE=C:\Users\<WindowsUser>\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\https\<ProjectName>.pem
SSL_KEY_FILE=C:\Users\<WindowsUser>\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\https\<ProjectName>.key

(After having a chat with the colleague, I now know that React automatically generates .env.development.local if it does not exist, and the .pem file was created from the certificate that was created by dotnet dev-certs https --trust.)
